# How long should the wait be for with editor status after submission?

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted paper to a journal of Elsevier. Now it has been 1 month from submission with status: "with editor".
Is this normal? And should I contact the journal to ask about the long time of that status?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you contact directly with editor via email. The processing time is depend by journals.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly email the editor. However, keep in mind that most editorial board members (except the editor-in-chief) are volunteers. As an editor myself, I can tell you that journal submission systems often send reminder emails to editors automatically. Also, it is not clearly defined what the "with editor" status even means. Perhaps the editor has invited multiple reviewers, but is waiting for enough reviewers to accept the paper review.

In summary, your main choices are to 1) wait; 2) bug the editor; or 3) withdraw the paper and submit to a different journal. It is common for the first round of review to take 3-4 months, so with only 1 month of delay my advice would be to wait patiently.